# Complex content in QTableView

Tags: qt, uitableview

We would like to do a TableView that allows complex content in its cells.
The TableView should be as generic that I can do simple stuff like in picture 1. [The left image is a simple example, where I fill a simple TableModel, set it for the TableView and display it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tj2kL.png)

[image]

But what if I want to add more complex content to one cell? Please again look at the first picture. The right part is more complex, for every cell we want to display an image, a description, and more description, so three items in one cell.

I understand, that I can put widgets to the cells of a TableView.
But, if I want to have a proper TableModel in the background, how would I store the data?

On top, the view should automatically resize when I make the widget of the TableView smaller the content should adapt

[image: when i make the widget of the TableView smaller the content should adapt]

So if I use TableView and want to resize, I would have to shovel the content from one colum to another. 
From what I understand, the columns also define the layout.

Would I be better of if I used a QGridLayout for this purpose? 
Do I have to define a completely new model for QGridLayout?

Thanks for any help! 
I am a newbie to QT and would appreciate your input a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Qt's proposed solution to having a complex view in each cell of a table view is to use a custom [delegate](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html#delegate-classes). Take a look at [Star Delegate example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-stardelegate-example.html), it demonstrates exactly this technique.

There are basically two options to proceed with a custom delegate: either you [subclass QStyledItemDelegate](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyleditemdelegate.html#subclassing-qstyleditemdelegate) (or its base class [QItemDelegate](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qitemdelegate.html) if you need to draw the items of Qt's datatypes somewhat specially) or subclass [QAbstractItemDelegate](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemdelegate.html) to have the full control over the delegate's appearance and behaviour.

However, your second requirement of automatic layout rearrangement on widget resizing suggests that your view doesn't really has to follow the underlying table's schema. Qt has a [flow layout](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-layouts-flowlayout-example.html) example which implements a layout with exactly this rearrange-on-resize property and I suppose the simplest approach would be just using this layout along with custom widgets representing the table model's cells. To make it happen you could implement a custom view class listening to the model's signals and creating/deleting widgets and updating the flow layout as necessary. [This book](https://www.qtrac.eu/aqpbook.html), even though a little outdated nowadays as it covers Qt4, contains a chapter (#6) on implementing a custom view which is not a subclass of `QAbstractItemView` but is just a widget updating itself as its underlying model updates. To me it feels the right approach to your problem.

Comment: Wow, Dmitry! 
Thanks a lot, that sounds like you answered every question. 
I will check what you said and feedback as soon as possible.

Comment: Finally we filled a QListView (&Model) and simply put list->setFlow(QListView::LeftToRight). That was easier for our approach, because FlowLayout as class is rather to be filled with widgets. Whereas QListView comes with its model and the data can be stored properly.

The display of three values in one cell did we via a Delegate as Dimitry suggested. We abadonned the table model, switched to the ListModel (as described above) and stored the three values that should appear in one cell in one item and set userData roles for the additional values.

Thanks Dimitry again, esp for the book hint!